# RSuite Cascader search text field not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a few RSuite components mixed in a mat-ui app. So far things work. However, I can't get the Cascader (the most needed...) to work properly. After not seeing the popup rendered at all I fixed that with css z-index for .rs-picker-menu. (I expected getPopupContainer={dialogRootRef.current} to also fix the display issue, but it seems to have no effect (ref is valid) and still mounts the popup in the body rather than with the dialog as the parent.)

The issue now is that when not displayed in-line (I want the pop-up version), the search text field is dead (can't focus/type). The css looks okay AFAICT and I tried removing all the event handlers in the dev tools. If I use {inline:true} everything does work. Any pointers on next steps appreciated.

https://rsuitejs.com/en/components/cascader

Answer (score 0):

The correct property is container={}.  getPopupContainer typechecked, but it's an Antd cascader prop, not RSuite's.